# Is it appropriate to question a girl about her virginity before marriage?

Tags: practical-islam, nikah, women

Is it right to question a girl about her virginity if someone is determined to get married to her. Or is it haram from an Islamic point of view?

Comment: It is a matter of acceptable cultural norms, not a question of Halaal or Haraam.

Comment: It is just that if a man is engaged to a girl can he ask about her virginity before marriage.  Is it haram or halal ?

Comment: Shouldn't it go both ways? If men are allowed to ask women, can the woman not ask the man an identical question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, asking such question is not permitted in Islam.

Even if she is not a virgin, and she repented from adultery, she shouldn't tell you that before marriage. It is called '`Al-Satr Ala Alnafs`' (`الستر علي النفس`)  which means '`self-covering`'.
Some people propose medical tests,  but this is also Haram in Islam, because this forces the doctor (either man or woman) to check her vagina, and this is prohibited unless there is a medical reason and it is required for her treatment. The prophet PBUH said:

> "Cover your Awra, except from your wife and your Malakt-Yameen (right
>   hands possess) [Saheeh Muslim]"
>
> احفظ عورتك إلا من زوجتك أو ما ملكت يمينك

Which means: do not show your sexual organs, except for your married partner, and for those whom your right hand possess.

> Also (prohibited are) women already married, except those whom your
>   right hands possess. [An-Nisaa / The Women 24]

And,

> If ye fear that ye shall not be able to deal justly with the orphans,
>   Marry women of your choice, Two or three or four; but if ye fear that
>   ye shall not be able to deal justly (with them), then only one, or (a
>   captive) that your right hands possess, that will be more suitable, to
>   prevent you from doing injustice. [An-Nisaa / The Women 3]

Resources which clarify this from many Imams and Olama:

1. [goo.gl/M9Ug2Y](http://goo.gl/M9Ug2Y) [In Arabic]
2. [goo.gl/cwt4Yy](http://goo.gl/cwt4Yy) [In Arabic]

The prophet PBUH said:

> Every one of my followers will be forgiven except those who expose
>   their wrongdoings 
> [Riadh-Al-Saliheen]

Comment: This is incorrect, _Satr-al-Nafs_ is NOT applicable to the case of someone who wants to asks; it says one should not **self-reveal** matters of virginity, i.e. without anyone asking about it.

Comment: @ٍShoaib, no it doesn't say "without anyone asking about it", this is your personal interpretation, it is an addition by you. Feqh is not about personal interpretations ... read fatwas at the end of the response

Comment: @Shoaib: Read this: 
 فما دام هذا الرجل قد تزوج تلك المرأة ولم يعلم بزناها فلا يبطل زواجه بذلك، وعليها أن تستر على نفسها ولا تخبر زوجها أو غيره بما وقعت فيه من الفاحشة 
  فقه الأسرة المسلمة - النكاح - المحرمات من النساء -  نكاح الزانية 
"If a man married this woman, and did not knows that she committed adultery (she is not virgin), then the marriage is correct despite this, and she MUSTapply "Sar-al_nafs", and she MUST NOT tell her husband or anyone about what she committed.
[Feqh of Muslim Family-Nikah - Women Not-allowed for marriage- Nekah of who committed adultery ]

Comment: @ٍShoaib: if you speak Arabic, view this video by Sheikh Mostafa AlAdawy, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4CYt1laqjM ... He says: "Should a woman tell the one who proposed for her marriage about that she is not virgin? the naswer is she MSUT NOT tell him, she MUST NOT tell him, she MUST NOT tell him, she should apply completely Satr-al-nafs"

Comment: @AshrafBashir It is not me interpreting anything here, you accidentally pasted the Q&A **Should a woman tell** the one who proposed for her marriage about that she is not virgin? That is EXACTLY what I said - these fatawa are related to self-revelation. Paste the whole question and answer to support your claim!

Comment: @Shoaib : View it yourself, you have the resources. Feqh Elnikah is not based on personal opinion dear! Eventhough I like the logical point which you mention, but Feqh is different from our own preferences.

Comment: @AshrafBashir Lol, you dont have any real source therefore you keep asking others to search dozens of pages. I didn't find anything of what you are claiming in several pages. You've _obviously_ read it so paste it here. Right now its your opinion that is under question of being personal, proof for my opinion is already pasted by you - ironically!

Comment: I already mentioned many, but it seems that you want to make it personal! i mentioned references and attached them: fawtas, hadiths, even videos! But you don't like Feqh opinion, and you do prefer your own opinion. I have nothing more to say! Do whatever you want. the OP asked about Islam opinion not personal opinion, Feqh is a science (Elm Shar'y) dear not personal opinions. If you don't want to follow it, so do what you like if you don't like feqh's opinion.

Comment: End of discussion. None of your pasted opinions or referenced pages address the question "Can a man ask?"

Comment: It seems that you don't speak arabic; That's why you cannot understand the resources!

Comment: A side advice brother, if you want to well understand Islamic Feqh an other Elom Shar'ia, you will have to study Arabic!

Comment: A humble request: **Please do not use URL shorteners, as they tend to expire (don't work) after a certain period of time**.

Answer (score 6):

Why you shouldn't ask her? It is your Right to ask about this. You should know about the past life of your partner as she has Right to ask you about yours.

> According to Quran "Good women belong to good men and bad women belong
>   to bad men."

Besides it's an logical and undeniable Right to now about your past life partner , expect if you wish to don't ask her. Absolutely you must be honest about your past life too.  It's a point in PSYCHOLOGY that will give you trust and more depth believe in your partner.

The mentioned reasons in "Ashraf Bashir" answer, belong to your view and idea and path of think about OTHER people in society not the one that will Marry you and be your partner for all the life.

Edited :

According to Quran :

> «و لا تنکحوا المشرکات حتی یؤمن و لامة مؤمنة خیر من مشرکة و لو اعجبتکم
>   و لا تنکحوا المشرکین حتی یؤمنوا و لعبد مؤمن خیر من مشرک و لو اعجبکم
>   اولئک یدعون الی النار و الله یدعوا الی الجنة و یبین آیاته للناس لعلهم
>   یتذکرون‏»

How can you be aware of your partner if you don't ask about her past, and research about her. You see It's exactly a Right that I was mentioned.

Comment: Your answer is very logical. I do accept your answer makes sense. I just wanted to know what is islamic point of view on this. Appreciate your response.

Comment: @Hope: in fact, it is not a Right in Islam. And your woman too does not have the right to ask also.  the OP (Atf) is asking for the "Islamic opinion", whether it is Halal or Haram, not what we think logically is a right for each partner. From the logical point of view, I do agree with you; But Islam is not measured by psychological opinions or logical opinions. What I mentioned is about and related to Marriage. Please revise many authorized Fatwas about the topic.

Comment: @AshrafBashir, Indeed it's not Haram in Islam anyway. Your conclusions in your answer only belong to Other people in society not your partner. You should ask about your partner, research about her past life, ask others and at last if nothing was wrong, you should "توکل علی الله انه کان بما تعملون بصیرا". It's exactly according to Sharia.

Comment: That's not right dear @hope :) You may revise many Arabic Fatwa here: http://goo.gl/M9Ug2Y and here: http://goo.gl/cwt4Yy. You are mixing your own personal logical opinion with Islam feqh opinion, which is not right my dear brother

Comment: The verse which you mention in the EDIT, is talking about getting married to  mushrekaat (those who believe in some god other than Allah, this is the Ishrak/sherk اشراك/شرك), not about virgins/non-virgins at all, that's why it says until they believe حتي يؤمنوا ... not about virginity at all!

Comment: @HOPE both Verses you quote are off topic *good woman...* (From surat an-Nur 24) this verse should be elaborated and not understood as is, as with repenting a former sinner would be qualified as chaste (and for that reason one should see/judge his fiancée as she is now and don't ask about her past) and the Verse (2:221) is about not marrying mushrikat or mushrikyn.

Comment: I agree, sharing their silly mistakes, does indeed make couples closer, but, also doesn't the same PSYCHOLOGY tell you that, it in fact increases the probability of them committing that mistake again, because the other partner considered it 'silly' ? (one might think, *if I do it again, he/she might forgive it again. No problem, go ahead!*).

Comment: @azam You should attention that it is about past life of each other not when they are living together. be with someone else when you are in a relation with someone else is totally betray and no science or ideology accept it.

Comment: I did not mean to criticize you or your answer. If that happened, I apologize. I thought you would appreciate reasoning, so I gave mine (without down voting), that, if couples share their past mistakes, they don't have other option other than forgiving (if they really love each other). Then, may not be cheating, but they might tend to do other mistakes which are annoying to the other. That's what I felt, and tried giving you a reason why you should [hide](http://www.ahya.org/amm/modules.php?name=Sections&op=viewarticle&artid=141) your mistakes.

Comment: But, you may ask it [here](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) for accurate answers if such a behavior is really seen or not. I'm sorry once again.

Comment: @azam Thanks for your illustration. Yes you're right, know such things about past of each other will have consequences and really hard to moderate it. But if it revealed somehow when you try to hide it, it will make a very worst situation, I think so.

Answer (score 4):

Before trying to give an Answer of your question we need to do some analysis:

- The only thing i found out, which would be acceptable and which you could clearly do is: *Making virginity a condition of Marriage*, so if you found out your wife was not a virgin your Marriage won't be valid or she will have to tell you -in this situation only-, but you must be aware that such things could be transmitted through her *Wali* or in the presence of her *Mahram*. (See for example this [fatwa](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=305548) in Arabic)
- And most scholars say it's not allowed for the future husband to ask about the past of his future wife (see [here](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=159249) and [here](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=158509) in this fatwas in Arabic or [here](http://islamqa.info/en/159398) in english). As nobody should disclose his sins as you may read in this [hadith](http://sunnah.com/muslim/55/68) and he should judge/see/accept his (future) wife as she is in the present or fromthe moment he began to get to know her on!
- On the other hand before wedding both (fiancé and fiancée) are *strangers* so they can only talk about things which are far away from awaking desire and lust or anything inappropriate which could lead to them!

So my answer would be "NO" you shouldn't ask, but you could make it a condition for marriage!

---

In some countries or regions there's a custom to ask the husband after the wedding if the wife is virgin this is also a prohibited matter, as nobody should disclose neither himself nor anybody else (especially his wife)...

---

And Allah knows best!

Answer (score 0):

when you are getting married via "ma2zoon" that's the person who's doing the marriage and officially  getting it done, he makes the statement of "zawagtoka....el-bekr el-rasheed" it means "you are getting married to a completely virgin" and so on the other side? if she wasn't virgin she must tell that and the words will be changed if she was married before, not virgin or not?

so this is the first step of marriage in islam that the man have to be knowing if he's getting married to  virgin or not? then what happened if they said "she was virgin while she wasn't" it's your choice if you want to keep her or not, Islam gave you the right the moment you find that she faked info/lied, that you can step back and never start that marriage that you was about to start in the first night.

Also note that trying to create a life for a wife must be based on trust & it's an act of "starting life without hidden info that could destroy my life later" so the girl must never lie about this either the man asked or not, but anyway even if the man didn't ask her that question "ma2zoon, always check and ask to make sure of what he will say"

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam Stack Exchange. Unlike the typical internet forum we expect answers here to be well elaborated, focused on answering the initial question and claims supported by evidences/references. I strongly recommend you to read [answer], to take our [tour] and to check our [help] to learn more about this site.

Answer (score -1):

well in islam you got it all wrong .. when 2 new partners are going to get married the sheikh (priest) in the ceremony tell the father to say after him " you will marry my daughter the virgin (el bekr el rasheed) so husband needs not to ask

if she is not virgin so she and her father lied and that is another question