# I had an unlawful relationship. Will Allah forgive me?

Tags: sex, relationships, zina, forgiveness

I had sex with my boyfriend who is already married. We are planning to marry now. I feel it will be a great injustice for his first wife since he has 3 little kids.

Will Allah forgive me for my sins and can I marry someone else? Do I have to tell him all these?

Comment: I'm sure you may find answers on your questions on the site: Allah may forgive, but you need to repent... that means you should leave the sin and the person you have sinned with. If he wants to marry you he must come and ask for your hand from your guardian. So anybody who may ask could marry you if you and your guardian accept. You don't have to tell anybody what happened.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider learning more about this site by taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Here some relevant posts http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28467/i-had-premarital-sex-with-my-cousin-now-i-have-questions-about-marriage , http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28069/sexual-sin-before-marriage and http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/26325/punishment-for-sins

Comment: And this answer your other question: ".. do I have to tell him all these ?.." [Questioning about girl's virginity before marriage?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28314/questioning-about-girls-virginity-before-marriage)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is personal matter. similar questions has been asked before.

Answer (score 3):

If you repent sincerely and refrain from such acts, Allah will forgive you Inshallah. Allah says in the Qur'an (interpretation of the meaning):

> [39:53] Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves
>   [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah . Indeed, Allah
>   forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the
>   Merciful."
>
> [3.133] And hasten to forgiveness from your Lord; and a Garden, the
>   extensiveness of which is (as) the heavens and the earth, it is
>   prepared for those who guard (against evil).

---

> **... can I marry someone else?**

You may marry someone else after you have repented. However, you should make sure you don't have any STDs.

---

> **Do I have to tell him all these?**

No, you should not tell him all these. The Prophet (peace be upon him) said,

> “All my community will be excused except those who commit sins openly.
>   Commiting them openly includes a man who does something shameful at
>   night and when morning comes tells someone that they did
>   such-and-such, while Allah had concealed it for them. They slept under
>   the cover of Allah, and they removed Allah s covering from themselves
>   in the morning.” [Bukhari, Muslim]

What this hadith teaches is that, you should not go around telling others about your sins.

Answer (score 1):

Your ques has 3 parts:
1. Will Allah forgive ??
2. Can you marry someone else or not ?
3. If you marry another, will u have to tell him all ?

Any sin Allah (swt) will forgive by his ultimate grace, as he is Rahmanur Raheem....more he described about his grace than rage. But condition is REPENTANCE ! REPENTANCE !! and REPENTANCE !!!

There are three conditions to repentance:

a. You should give up the sin
b. You should regret having done it
c. You should resolve never to go back to it
[And Allah knows what you think, what you might think and even what you might not think]

About the sin you committed, Allah says in Quran (interpretation):

> "And those who, when they have committed Faahishah (illegal sexual intercourse) or wronged themselves with evil, remember Allaah and ask forgiveness for their sins; — and none can forgive sins but Allaah — and do not persist in what (wrong) they have done, while they know" -- [Al ‘Imraan 3:135]

To see an excellent example of repentance in case of adultery follow the hadiths in the given links:
http://sunnah.com/muslim/29/34
http://sunnah.com/muslim/29/36

To know more read [this](https://islamqa.info/en/46683).

Now answer to your 2nd question, you can not marry someone who is chaste unless you repent. But once you truly repent your sin is waived and you can marry...
To know more read [this](https://islamqa.info/en/199600).

To answer the 3rd part, in any case you should repent to Allah and conceal your sins from anyone else...

Abu Hurayrah said:

> I heard the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) say: “All of my ummah will be forgiven except those who sin openly. It is a part of sinning openly when a man does something at night, then the following morning when Allaah has concealed his sin, he says, ‘O So and so, I did such and such last night,’ when all night his Lord has concealed him and the next morning he uncovers what Allaah had concealed.” (Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 5721; Muslim, 2990)...

So you should not confess your sin unless it's open by itself. But if it's open, then the punishment as per Sharia (islamic law) has to be imparted (in your case , as you are unmarried it's 100 lashes of beating)

To know more: [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/3365)  and [islamweb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&lang=E&Id=84052)

Answer (score -1):

1. Your boyfriend being a father of 3 who **cheated his wife**, he can easily cheat and betray to you also. **If he find other women he will leave you also**.
2. Punishments
   In sharia(Islamic) law the punishment for the person(unmarried) involves in illegal sex is to beat **100 lashes**(like with hunter).

The punishment for the person(Married) who involves in illegal sex is to give **DEATH** by beating with stones.

3. You are **playing with five life**, you can get other man for marriage, be careful and fear with ALLAH. what you do now, you have to give answer for everything on the day of judgement, **everything is getting recorded by angels on your shoulders.**

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider reading [answer], the most part of your answer doesn't even address OP's questions instead of analyzing or condemning and giving the explicit punishment which would apply for such a sin. I strongly recommend you to take the [tour] and check the [help] for more information on how this site works.